# Grouping images based on the face in the images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, face-recognition

I have roughly 5000 photographs of various persons that I am organising according to the person. As a result, I intend to develop a Python script to carry out the task. I'm new to the Opencv library and am unsure whether this is feasible to do. To locate the faces in the photos, I wrote the code below.

```
import cv2

def find_faces(imagePath,results_path):

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_eye.xml")

image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray,scaleFactor=1.3,minNeighbors=3,minSize=(30, 30))

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    roi_color = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    if len(eyes) >= 2:
        cv2.imwrite(results_path + str(w) + str(h) + '_faces.jpg', roi_color)
```

Now I need to organise the photographs per person.Any help with the next steps is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Facial detection is one thing, recognition (and grouping) is another thing altogether, it requires some ML. Think of it this way, can **you** group faces together with complete accuracy 100% of the time? Even for similar faces? How about with different angles and colors? How good are you for different ethnicities than your own? If not, what makes you think a simple algorithm / library can?

Comment: look at "facenet". -- voting to close, "asking for recommendations". please review [ask] and [help/on-topic]. research (googling) is your responsibility.

Comment: @OferSadan, I am not expecting 100% accuracy, I need to manual work but if there is any automation which helps upto some extent is good for me. I am not a ML developer so want to know any support for this kind of tasks.

Answer (score 1):

As a fan of `dlib / face_recognition` libs I'd propose to use them (look at face_recognition tutorial - it's really easy)) to:

1. Create a dictionary with face encodings for all images and pathes to the image files:
2. Loop through the face encodings and compare each one with the rest: you don't need 100% similarity, normally 72..75% (0.28..0.25) means the same individual.
   I'm using something like that to store face data:

   ```
    class Face_Dictionary():
        """[The class contains all data structures to store in memory as 
           well as load and save to file
           face encodings data, including picture file full path and 
           face location for each face on every picture]
        """    

    def __init__(self, dicfilename="", mode="load"): #Create all data objects
        self.mode = mode
        self.dicfilename = dicfilename
        self.fl_Loaded = False
        self.fl_Saved = False
        self.Encodings = []
        self.Names = []
        self.facelocs = []
        self.fd = {"encodings": self.Encodings, "names": self.Names, 
                    "locations": self.facelocs}
        if bool(self.dicfilename) and self.mode == "load":
            self.fl_Loaded = self.load()


    def __del__(self): #redefine method del()
        del(self.Encodings)
        del(self.Names)
        del(self.facelocs)
        del(self.fd)

    def load(self):
        """
        [Loads a dictionary with face encodings from Pickle-type file into self.fd]

        Args:
            dicfilename ([str]): [Pickle-type file *.pkl]

        Returns:
            [bool]: [True if loaded. Also sets self.fl_Loaded as True]
        """
        if bool(self.dicfilename) and self.mode == "load":
            try:
                f = open(self.dicfilename, "rb")
            except (IOError, EOFError) as e:
                print("[ERR] Не можу знайти/прочитати файл кодувань обличь: %s" % e)
                return False
            else:
                if os.path.getsize(self.dicfilename) > 15:
                    self.fd = load(f)
                    self.fl_Loaded = True
                else:
                    f.close()
                    return  False
            f.close()
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def save(self):
        """
        [Saves dictionary with face encodings to Pickle-type file]

        Args:
            None

        Returns:
            [bool]: [True if self.fd has been saved to the original <self.dicfilename.pkl>.
            Also sets self.fl_Saved as True]
        """
        if bool(self.dicfilename) and self.mode == "save":
            try:
                f = open(self.dicfilename, "wb")
            except OSError:
                print("[ERR] Не можу створити файл бази даних %s" % self.dicfilename)
                return False
            dump(self.fd, f, protocol=HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
            f.close()
            self.fl_Saved = True
            return True

    def save_as(self, filename):
        """
        [Saves dictionary with face encodings to Pickle-type file with specified name]

        Args:
            filename ([str]): [Pickle-type file *.pkl]

        Returns:
            [bool]: [True if self.fd has been saved to the original <self.dicfilename.pkl>.
            Also sets self.fl_Saved as True]
        """
        if bool(filename):
            try:
                f = open(filename, "wb")
            except OSError:
                print("[ERR] Не можу створити файл бази даних %s" % filename)
                return False
            dump(self.fd, f, protocol=HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
            f.close()
            self.fl_Saved = True
            return True
   ```